# Ошибка NameError: name 'HtmlParser' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, аннотации

Есть класс HtmlParser и у него метод parsing. Если написать так

```
class HtmlParser:
    def parsing(rule:str) -> HtmlParser:
        ...
```

То будет ошибка NameError: name 'HtmlParser' is not defined. Почему так происходит и баг ли это?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/5909792) есть обходы этой ошибки:

1. **Создание пустышки:**

   ```
   class HtmlParser:
       pass


   class HtmlParser:
       def parsing(self, rule: str) -> HtmlParser:
           pass
   ```
2. **Использование строки:**

   ```
   class HtmlParser:
       def parsing(self, rule: str) -> 'HtmlParser':
           pass
   ```
3. **Вручную в добавить в аннотацию метода `parsing` возвращаемый тип:**

   ```
   class HtmlParser:
       def parsing(self, rule: str):
           pass

   HtmlParser.parsing.__annotations__['return'] = HtmlParser
   ```

Если нужно прописать такое у аргумента метода, например для `def parsing(self, rule: str, other_parser)`:

```
HtmlParser.parsing.__annotations__['other_parser'] = HtmlParser
```

---

Самый разумный вариант, думаю – использовать строку.

Comment: «Создание пустышки» — у меня есть подозрение, что такая пустышка будет считаться линтерами отдельным классом и это сведёт на нет всю суть этого синтаксиса вообще

Comment: Да, пустышка – плохо, это будет другой тип. По PEP предполагается использовать `'HtmlParser'`.